# p-table paginatorLeft & paginatorRight do not show up

Tags: angular, primeng, paginator

I have a p-table that shows the paginator control fine at the bottom. However when I tried to add the paginatorLeft or the paginatorRight tags, neither of them would show up:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="paginatorLeft" let-state>
  {{state.totalRecords}}
  <button type="button" pButton icon="fa-refresh"></button>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="paginatorRight">
  <button type="button" pButton icon="fa-cloud-upload"></button>
</ng-template>
```

Here's the stackbliz link for the project - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x87wzc?file=app%2Fprovider-search%2Fprovider-search.component.html

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a mistake in PrimeNG doc. It should be `paginatorleft` instead of `paginatorLeft`. See [table code](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/table/table.ts), line 370)

So replace `pTemplate="paginatorLeft"` by `pTemplate="paginatorleft"` and it should work.

Comment: that was exactly the issue. fixed!